# some transactions having an "Error connecting to AuthorizeNet"

Tags: authorize.net

Some of my transactions having this error: `"Error connecting to AuthorizeNet"` basically null

[image]

but sometimes some transactions goes totally fine. Is this from my end or from Authorize.net? Is someone had this issue before? Thanks

Comment: Authorize.Net is reliable so the issue most likely resides on your end. Your host may not be reliable.

Comment: @JohnConde maybe it's because outdated curl version?

Comment: That's possible but hard to say for sure

Comment: ended up they were updating cert.pem but didn't mention anything, until people start complaining it https://twitter.com/AuthorizeNet/status/817153644147552256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using the php sdk, check out their recent post on this. it solved the issue for me:

https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Is-Live-Environment-Down-Keep-Getting-quot-Error-connecting-to/m-p/56598#M31379